# How to create Treeview(+/-) having plus and minus and also having checkbox

Tags: html, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on design part I want to create plus/minus treeview structure and having checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use lists inside lists and each list has the checkbox before it and you can use the `+` in CSS which means immediately following.

```
input[type=checkbox] + ol {
  /* style when you want the ol to be collapsed */
  /* could be as simple as display none */
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + ol {
  /* style when you want the ol to be expanded */
  /* could be as simple as display block */
}
```